# Visit South Korea with US Visa

Tags: indian-citizens, south-korea, us-visa

I am an India passport holder with a USA F1 visa. Is it possible to visit South Korea (departing from USA and with return flight to USA as well) for 2 weeks without applying for a separate visa? This trip is solely for travel purpose.

My Visa, as well as my passport, is not expiring at least for 1 year after my intended date of travel.